Power Query Filtered Rows based on value
I have two sources - a master list (Source1) and a weekly update (Source2). I want to check against ID numbers in Source2

filter for IDs that are not in Source1 and

check that the new IDs in Source2 doesn't contain the string "Closed" in the "Status"column in Source2


I want the master list to basically include all the new IDs added in the weekly update list and make sure not to include any IDs that have been closed.
let
  // Merge Source1 and Source2 (use a Full Outer Join to get all rows from both tables)
  MergedTables = Table.NestedJoin(Source1, {"ID"}, Source2, {"ID"}, JoinKind.FullOuter),

  // Expand Source2 columns
  ExpandedSource2Data = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"MergedTables", 
    {{"Title",each Text.From(_)}, {"Problem Description",each Text.From(_)}, {"Originator",each Text.From(_)}, {"WOA/Event/Dev Number",each Text.From(_)}, {"Status", each Text.From(_)}, {"Impacted Subsystems", each Text.From(_)}, {"Date Entered", each Text.From(_)}, {"Date Closed", each Text.From(_)}, {"Problem Date",each Text.From(_)}, {"Disposition to Close", each Text.From(_)}, {"Root Cause of the Problem",each Text.From(_)}, {"Final Disposition", each Text.From(_)}}, 
    {{"Source2_Title",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Problem Description",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Originator",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_WOA/Event/Dev Number",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Status",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Impacted Subsystems",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Date Entered",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Date Closed",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Problem Date",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Disposition to Close",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Root Cause of the Problem",each Text.From(_)}, {"Source2_Final Disposition", each Text.From(_)}}), 

  // Filter rows where ID is in Source2 but not in Source1 and Status in Source2 is not 'Closed'
  FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(#"ExpandedSource2Data", each ([ID] <> null and [Source2][ID] <> null and [Source2][Status] <> "PR Closed")),

  // Combine Source1 and FilteredRows
  CombinedTables = Table.Combine({Source1, FilteredRows}),
  #"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(CombinedTables, {"Source2_Title", "Source2_Problem Description", "Source2_Originator", "Source2_WOA/Event/Dev Number", "Source2_Status", "Source2_Impacted Subsystems", "Source2_Date Entered", "Source2_Date Closed", "Source2_Problem Date", "Source2_Disposition to Close", "Source2_Root Cause of the Problem", "Source2_Final Disposition"})

in
  #"Removed columns"

I added the each Text.From(_) because it keeps on giving me an error stating : [Expression.Error] We cannot convert the value 3 to type Text....although it is still not resolved.
Example data:
Source1/master list:



ID
Title
Description
Conclusion
Status




120
Title120
Desc120
Conclusion120
120 Closed


137
Title137
Desc137
Conclusion137
137 Open


142
Title142
Desc142
Conclusion142
142 Fields Complete



Source2/weekly update list:



ID
Title
Description
Conclusion
Status




120
Title120
Desc120
Conclusion120
120 Closed


137
Title137
Desc137
Conclusion137
137 Open


142
Title142
Desc142
Conclusion142
142 Fields Complete


001
Title001
Desc001
Conclusion001
001 Closed


006
Title006
Desc006
Conclusion006
006 ID Closed


600
Title600
Desc600
Conclusion600
600 NEW


700
Title700
Desc700
Conclusion700
700 Open



Desired merged output with only the new IDs added to the master list but not anything that was closed a while back and not in master:



ID
Title
Description
Conclusion
Status




120
Title120
Desc120
Conclusion120
120 Closed


137
Title137
Desc137
Conclusion137
137 Open


142
Title142
Desc142
Conclusion142
142 Fields Complete


600
Title600
Desc600
Conclusion600
600 NEW


700
Title700
Desc700
Conclusion700
700 Open




could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

and when you provide the sample data, please provide it AS TEXT which can be copy/pasted and not as a screenshot. You can use a Markdown Tables Generator to format the text readably.

Added sample tables for input and desired output!

//powerquery code for Table1 that merges in Table2 where ID is new and Table2.Status does not contain Closed
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"ID"},Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [Status]=null or not Text.Contains([Status],"Closed")), {"ID"}, "Table2", JoinKind.RightAnti),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Table2"}),
ColumnsToExpand  =List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Removed Other Columns", "Table2"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
#"Expanded Table" = Source & Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Table2", ColumnsToExpand, ColumnsToExpand)
in #"Expanded Table"



This gives me an error because I think when it is trying to expand columns, columns with the same name exists. " [Expression.Error] The field 'Title' already exists in the record."

My bad. Edited and fixed. Should have removed all other columns rather then removing specific columns. Hence the importance of sample data
